# jensen shannon divergence is always inf

Tags: scipy, word-embedding, scipy-spatial

I have used spacy for text (sentence)  embedding where ensemble type is `mean` and embedding dimension is 300. Here I want to find `jensen shannon divergence` between two sentences.

```
from scipy.spatial import distance
a = np.matrix([[-3.28254097, -1.88733395,  0.45432703, ..., -3.11750075,-0.67481474,  0.16454482]])
b = np.matrix([[-3.14694506, -4.70102323,  1.50877541, ..., -1.04084573,0.60134094,  1.34008962]])
distance.jensenshannon(a, b, axis=1)
```

shape of both a & b is (1, 300)

I always get divergence as `inf`. I have tested for different pair of sentences and result is always same. I have tested with fist N elements and again divergence is `inf`.
Looks like it is because elements are negative number so what is work around I can compute valid JS Drift in such case.

Thanks in advance

Comment: The [Jensen-Shannon divergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%E2%80%93Shannon_divergence) measures the distance between two *probability distributions*.  The required inputs of the SciPy function are two probability vectors (i.e. for each vector, the values are between 0 and 1 and the sum is 1).  It doesn't make sense to apply it to the data that you have shown.

Comment: Can you give any example where JS divergence is computed between two different  word embeddings  like how to transform word embedding to probability distribution first before applying JS divergence in python  ? is softmax right approach or there are more suitable transformations?

Comment: @BharatSharma try using `Word2Vec` or something to convert word embedding to probability distribution

Comment: @GOKU Can you give one example in python . I am having negative elements in vector , there could be zero probability issue also.

Comment: go through this tutorial ; https://neptune.ai/blog/word-embeddings-guide ; there is plenty of material on the internet.

Comment: Must the distance metric be Jensen-Shannon specifically? Why not something like [cosine distance](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.cosine.html)?

Comment: @Nick oDell It's like I am doing some R&D and would like to test something on JS distance.

Comment: One approach to doing this would be to use a [MinMaxScaler](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.MinMaxScaler.html) to scale the vector to values between 0 and 1, then divide the resulting vector by its sum. Another approach would be to use softmax. In fact, there are probably many ways of doing this. I'm not sure how to answer this question, because there are so many ways this could be done.